# How can SignHash data using RSACryptoServiceProvider in dotnet 8

Tags: c#, .net-core, cryptography, rsacryptoserviceprovider

From the code below if get RSA key from Stakeholders Certificate which is the file that I load from file with a password.

The code below does not work in two cases the first is `rsaPrivateKey.ExportParameters(false)` the `privateKey!.SignHash(hash, oid)` gives me errors
when i set signHash using the above code i get exeception

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Object contains only the public half of a key pair. A private key must also be provided.
```

But if I set it to true `rsaPrivateKey.ExportParameters(false)` I get exceptions

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The requested operation is not supported.
         at System.Security.Cryptography.CngKey.Export(CngKeyBlobFormat format)
         at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng.ExportParameters(Boolean includePrivateParameters)
```

How can I make it work in Windows 10 and dotnet 8 project i want to SignHash data using RSACryptoServiceProvider.

```cs
RSA rsaPrivateKey = this.StakeHolderCert.GetRSAPrivateKey();
RSAParameters rsaParams = rsaPrivateKey.ExportParameters(true);
var privateKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
privateKey.ImportParameters(rsaParams);

byte[] fullArray = privateKey!.SignHash(hash, oid);
string _base64String3 = Convert.ToBase64String(fullArray);
```

Comment: Regarding the first error: `ExportParameters(false)` exports only the public parameters. However, the private key is required for signing, so it is no wonder that this does not work.

Comment: Regarding the second error: Where does `StakeHolderCert` come from? Was this loaded from a .pfx? On Windows (and macOS in contrast to Linux), `X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable` must be specified for this, as the keys are not exportable by default. Otherwise you will get this error message, s. [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/26031).

Comment: BTW, have you tried using `rsaPrivateKey` *directly* for signing, i.e. `rsaPrivateKey.SignHash()`, s. online here https://dotnetfiddle.net/JqUXq9?